# AM PM not inserting into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Have a field curdate, like

```
 <?php
    $date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $time= date("l, F d, Y h:i:s A"); 
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $time; ?>" name="curdate" id="curdate"/>
```

it will take the current date and time to database.

There is another column 'curdatesql', it will take the above time to mysql time format:

```
 "' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['curdate']) . '",
 STR_TO_DATE("' . $this->SanitizeForSQL($formvars['curdate']) . '","%W, %M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p"),
```

The problem is its  not taking the AM, PM part into mysql table...Why is that?

Its taking like : 2013-07-20 13:26:35 (No AM PM present).

Comment: Why do you need AM / PM when you have a 24h-format? so your date format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. Now `if(hh >= 12) {PM} else {AM}`

Comment: ^ this and `$hours % 12` should give u the right AM/PM hours

Comment: check your field type in database if it is `datetime`, will accept the format `2013-07-20 13:26:35` if you want to store am/pm change the field type to `varchar`

Comment: @Kathiravan: If it is only AM / PM he should change it to `char(2)`. But as I explained in my answer, he should use DATETIME only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has several [date and time formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html). You seem to use DATETIME which displays values in the form `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. Note that `HH` is a 24-hour format.

You should not store AM/PM extra, as this would be completely redundant. In the best case, you would waste memory, in worst case you would get inconsistencies.

Instead, you should handle this in the presentation layer:

```
if(hh >= 12) {
    PM
} else {
    AM
}

hours = hh % 12
```

Note that you can use MySQL [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to get the format you like. It could look like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(myStoredDatabaseAttribute, '%h %p') FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

My sql the date is stored in 24 hours format and also in binary. If the representation requires a 12 hour display format you will have to handle it in the presentation layer.